# Проблема с индексированием сайта поисковыми роботами

Tags: php, javascript, seo

Доброго времени суток всем! Сложилась следующая проблема при сканировании моего сайта поисковой робот создает много левых ссылок. В чем может быть проблема ??

Пример

есть страница мой-сайт.ру/blog/
Естественно на всех страницах сайта есть навигация
Поисковик заходит на страницу /blog/ и пытается открыть все ссылки из навигации сайта со следующим адресом

мой-сайт.ру/blog/o-nas/

Хотя такой ссылки не существует в принципе.

Существует ссылка 
мой-сайт.ру/o-nas/

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить ??

Comment: например на странице `мой-сайт.ру/blog/` ссылка указана как `<a href="o-nas/">`

Comment: Да действительно по коду PHP ссылка выводилась в таком формате но потом обрабатывалась скриптом поэтому тяжело было найти проблему. Спасибо

Comment: @Grundy и получить 404 при вложеной навигации

Comment: @Naumov, не понял комментарий:)

Answer (score 1):

Поисковые роботы индексируют ваш сайт в тот момент, когда им удобно. В том числе, могут проиндексировать его тогда, когда на вашем сайте были ошибочные ссылки. Поисковый робот запоминает эти ссылки и в следующий раз пытается вновь обратиться к ним. Это решится через некоторое время, когда поисковый робот убедиться, что сохраненные ссылки более недоступны.